# NSTextView Inserting character twice on handling textDidChange

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, caret

I have intercepted the textDidChange event of an NSTextView in an effort to detect the beginning and end of an escaped statement.  The trouble is it seems when I actually try to do anything the typed character is inserted twice.

For example

- . becomes ..
- { becomes {{
- | becomes ||

Does anyone understand why this might be? I've posted the code from the textview delegate below.

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    //get the caret position
    NSInteger insertionPoint = [self.manuscriptTextView selectedRange].location;
    NSInteger low =insertionPoint -2;
    NSRange r = {low, insertionPoint};
    NSString* parse = [self.manuscriptTextView.textStorage.string substringWithRange:r];
    if([parse isEqualToString:@"{{"])
    {
        printf("begin{{\n");
    }
    else if([parse isEqualToString:@"}}"])
    {
        printf("}}end\n");
    }


}
```

Comment: so if you comment our `-textDidChange` you don't have this issue, correct?

Comment: Indeed, commenting out textdidchange stops this from happening.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: Yes I hadn't noticed it because I had another exception on constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the applications was a document based applications, and the autosave paradigm for NSDocument was not fully implemented causing an **exception** to occur.  Apparently when there is an **exception on modification of a UI controlled by NSDocument**, strange things like this can happen.